# Why am I getting two output messages with the same answer

Tags: java

I am calculating the sum of two decimals. I get two inputs from the user in the form of decimal numbers I am getting the sum of numbers. It works as expected apart from the fact that once I press return on the first output to close the dialog box I get a second dialog box with the same calculation. I have no idea why this is happening

```
public class SumOfApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //variables
        double[] decimalNumbers;
        decimalNumbers = new double[2];
        double[] sumNumbers;

        //create objects
        SumOf s;
        s = new SumOf();

        //input
        for (int i = 0; i < decimalNumbers.length; i++) {
            decimalNumbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your numbers"));
        }

        //set
        s.setDecimalNumbers(decimalNumbers);

        //compute
        s.computeSumNumbers();

        //get
        sumNumbers = s.getSumNumbers();

        //output
        for (int i = 0; i < decimalNumbers.length; i++) {
            // Output
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sumNumbers[i] + " the sum of the two numbers");

        }
    }
} public class SumOf {
    //variables
    private double[] decimalNumbers;
    private final double[] sumNumbers = new double[2];

    //constructor
    public SumOf() {

    }

    //set
    public void setDecimalNumbers(double[] decimalNumbers) {
        this.decimalNumbers = decimalNumbers;
    }

    //compute
    public void computeSumNumbers() {
        for (int i = 0; i < decimalNumbers.length; i++) {
            sumNumbers[i] = decimalNumbers[i] + decimalNumbers[i];
        }
    }

    //get
    public double[] getSumNumbers() {
        return sumNumbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code confuses me. Why are you going through the array adding the same number together, effectively multiplying each by 2? Why are you putting the sum into an array? It makes no sense. Shouldn't you have one single sum variable that holds the sum the array values? The code is only doing what you are telling it to do.

Comment: You will want to learn and practice [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) so that you know what each line of your code is doing.

Comment: well `decimalNumbers` is an array of length `2`, and you're opening the message dialog in a loop based on the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the output of the SumOfApp:

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the sum of the two numbers : " + s.getSumNumbers()[0]);` instead of the loop for.

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
public void computeSumNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < decimalNumbers.length; i++) {
        sumNumbers[i] = decimalNumbers[i] + decimalNumbers[i];
    }
}
```

is not doing what it is supposed to - at least what the name of class and function implies its doing. What it does is two times each number stored in first and then second array element. If you want to simply compute sum, the do it:

```
public void computeSumNumbers() {
   sumNumbers[0] = decimalNumbers[0] + decimalNumbers[1];
}
```

Of course, then you dont need sumNumbers to be an array.

> It works as expected apart from the fact that once I press return on the first output to close the dialog box I get a second dialog box with the same calculation.

its because you iterate the decimalNumbers and since its length is 2, you see your dialog twice. It should suffice to show dialog only once:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sumNumbers[0] + " the sum of the two numbers");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the "sumNumbers" variable as a double variable rather than an array and fix the array annotations in both classes.

```
public class SumOfApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //variables
    double[] decimalNumbers;
    decimalNumbers = new double[2];
    double sumNumbers;

    //create objects
    SumOf s;
    s = new SumOf();

    //input
    for (int i = 0; i < decimalNumbers.length; i++) {
        decimalNumbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your numbers"));
    }

    //set
    s.setDecimalNumbers(decimalNumbers);

    //compute
    s.computeSumNumbers();

    //get
    sumNumbers = s.getSumNumbers();

        // Output
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s.sumNumbers + " the sum of the two numbers");

}
```

}

```
class SumOf {
//variables
private double[] decimalNumbers;
 double sumNumbers = 0;

//constructor
public SumOf() {

}

//set
public void setDecimalNumbers(double[] decimalNumbers) {
    this.decimalNumbers = decimalNumbers;
}

//compute
public void computeSumNumbers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < decimalNumbers.length; i++) {
        sumNumbers = decimalNumbers[i] + decimalNumbers[i];
    }
}

//get
public double getSumNumbers() {
    return sumNumbers;
}
```

}